# SQL Server Job exit with error when running in scheduled job but runs fine when running job manually

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a job on SQL Server 2005 running a ssis package.

The package as the protection level 'EncryptSensitiveWithPassword'

the job has only one step of type Operating sytem(CmdExec), since the ssis uses an excel output file and the server is 64bits

I do pass the password in the command

run as a server proxy

The job runs fine when I right click on 'Start job at step...' but when the job runs from the schedule it fails with error :

... Code: 0xC0016016     Source:       Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x80070002 "The system cannot find the file specified.". You may not be authorized to access this information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error. Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error ...

thanks for your input

Comment: Is there a chance that you are running with different security credentials when hitting the manual trigger vs the scheduled trigger? That would explain the difference. Is there a run-as option or setting for the scheduled task?

Comment: the domain proxies uses the same credentials as hitting the manual trigger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The error you have posted is because you left the default setting for the ProtectionLevel property of your package set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey".

Source: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic565927-147-1.aspx

To find the property follow the steps:

1. Open you package in VS
2. Click on the Control Flow panel
3. Go to Properties